# Anything that has a color of bone

Tags: word-request

First of all I need to make sure if there is an adjective (color name) in English which is used for describing something's color that has a **color of bone**. Then if there is, then what adjective it would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bone" happens to be a standard color name used in English. It is a very pale brownish off-white. Unlike some color names (olive?, peach?), "bone" is pretty much the color of the referenced object: clean dry bones from land animals.

Comment: Thank you @Lorel C ; just do you mean that "bone" and "olive" are normal colors in BrE (as they are in my language too)?

Comment: My English is USA type. Not sure about BrE, but over here, "bone" as a color name will be understood by anybody who has an interest in colors at all. That is if a person understands "lavender", "plum", "charcoal", and "teal", they should recognize "bone". Of course there are people like "Roy G. Biv" whose color vocabulary is limited to 10 words (his own name + brown, gray, and white). Those people will not probably realize the color name "bone".

Comment: Then what do you normally say @Lorel C? I.e. would you probabely say: **charcoal blak suit** or just **charcoal suit**? Or would you say **olive green t-shirt** or just **olive t-shirt**?

Comment: LawrenceC makes a good point in his answer. When using color names whose primary meaning is something else (like charcoal or bone), if it isn't clear from the context that you are talking about colors, you should either attach the suffix "-colored" (bone-colored) or add another (exclusively) color name (charcoal gray, charcoal black). So, yes, prob. good to be clear: "charcoal black suit", "olive green t-shirt. If you just said, "He wore his bone shirt to the interview," it might sound like he wore this:  https://www.dhgate.com/product/human-skeleton-t-shirt-framework-bone-short/405489969.html

Answer (score 7):

There's no simple, common word that means the color of bone in English.

When presenting a list of colors to someone, particularly for decorative use, that's a "creative" context that allows figurative uses of words.  So you can specify words that only mean colors, or words that have strong common and unambiguous imagery - many flowers, fruits, and jewels are among those.  Bone is such a word.

> Choose a color for the background: Red, Green, Blue, White, Orange, Pomegranate, Olive, Grape, Topaz, Emerald, Bone.

Without this context, the suffix "-colored" works and is needed.

> I liked the bone-colored wall.
>
> I liked the bone wall (you're saying the wall is made of bone).

Answer (score 4):

The best option is "bone-grey" as this is short and unambiguous.

Colour names can be classed as:

- First level (eg Red) which is words that only mean the name of the colour.
- Second level (eg Lilac) which is words that mean something else but also used as a colour,
- And third level (eg "Apple") occasionally used to describe colours, mostly by paint companies or people making lists.

"Bone" is a colour with hex value #[e3dac9](https://www.colorhexa.com/e3dac9). This is a third level colour name, only used in technical contexts.

The actual colour of bones isn't fixed.  When in the living body, they are slightly pink (due to the presence of blood).  Fresh dry bones are white and older dried bones become yellow. Powdered bone is often white or grey.

It is possible to say "bone coloured".  But this presents ambiguity, as bone changes colour with age. Better is to say "bone-grey", and [this is used for a light grey](https://www.suitlab.com.au/products/boys-suit-bone-grey)

(There is a similar problem with "skin coloured" which is the translation of the term used in some languages. But it, of course, ambiguous in a culture in which there are people of various skin colours.)

Comment: how about "beige"?

Comment: how about it?  Living bone is slightly pink, older oxidised bones could be described as "beige" Fresh bone would not be called beige.  The point is that bones change colour

Answer (score 2):

About colour names in general ...

- It's worth noting that very many native speakers of the same culture **do not agree** on colour names, and will argue at length about them.
- Across cultures, it **can be impossible to translate colour names** because of non-matching colour spaces ("brown" and "purple" might both translate to "X", which really means something closest to "dark", and "Y" might translate to "Yellow" or "orange", depending on detail not expressed in English.  (The same is true of animal names and many others.)
- **Manufacturers** of paint and cloth often have very fanciful names they make up and which would not be understood exactly by the general public
- **Scientists** tend to use works such as *Werner's Nomenclature of Colours: Adapted to Zoology, Botany, Chemistry, Mineralogy, Anatomy, and the Arts*, which is what Darwin used and has been re-issued.  (I don't believe current scientists use this book, but it's widely available and illustrates the issue.)
- **Printing** and other graphic arts tend to use Pantone reference charts when they wish to be precise
- In **theatre and film lighting** it's common to use colour swatches from Lee Lighting or similar
- In **computers**, the "X11" colour names are widely used, along with other similar schemes [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names), but like the other naming schemes, many would not agree that those names specifically refer to those colours in general English